# Create duplicate file and rename it

Tags: linux, bash

I want duplicates of the files with different name.
I am currently trying out these commands before putting them into my bash script.

```
$ set dir = /somewhere/states
$ find $dir -name "total.txt" -type f | xargs ls -1
/somewhere/states/florida/fixed.fl_Asite_ttl/somewhere/total.txt
/somewhere/states/hawaii/fixed.hi_Bsite_ttl/somewhere/total.txt
/somewhere/states/kentucky/fixed.ky_Asite_ttl/somewhere/total.txt
/somewhere/states/michigan/fixed.mi_Csite_ttl/somewhere/total.txt
/somewhere/states/texas/fixed.tx_Vsite_ttl/somewhere/total.txt
```

I know I can rename file using something like this, but it isn't exactly what I want:

```
$ find $dir -name "total.txt" -exec sh -c 'cp {} `dirname {}`/`basename {} `why.xls' \;
/somewhere/states/florida/fixed.fl_Asite_ttl/somewhere/total.txtwhy.xls
/somewhere/states/hawaii/fixed.hi_Bsite_ttl/somewhere/total.txtwhy.xls
/somewhere/states/kentucky/fixed.ky_Asite_ttl/somewhere/total.txtwhy.xls
/somewhere/states/michigan/fixed.mi_Csite_ttl/somewhere/total.txtwhy.xls
/somewhere/states/texas/fixed.tx_Vsite_ttl/somewhere/total.txtwhy.xls
```

May I know how to copy the files and have the new files in the same dir?
below are the examples.
I want to name the new files as everything behind "fixed." and before "/somewhere" and changing the file extension as well

```
/somewhere/states/florida/fixed.fl_Asite_ttl/somewhere/fl_Asite_ttl.xls
/somewhere/states/hawaii/fixed.hi_Bsite_ttl/somewhere/hi_Bsite_ttl.xls
/somewhere/states/kentucky/fixed.ky_Asite_ttl/somewhere/ky_Asite_ttl.xls
/somewhere/states/michigan/fixed.mi_Csite_ttl/somewhere/mi_Csite_ttl.xls
/somewhere/states/texas/fixed.tx_Vsite_ttl/somewhere/tx_Vsite_ttl.xls
```

Update:
/somewhere/states/florida_fixed_ttl/fixed.fl_Asite_ttl/somewhere/total.txt

Comment: `cat somefile.txt > newfile.txt` ?

Comment: hi @T4rk1n , i wasn't intend to override the files? I'm trying to copy and rename the files. To have 2 similar files in the same dir but with diff names.

Comment: that line will do exactly that, read the content of a file and pipe it into a new file.

Comment: @T4rk1n, oh right, then how bout using bash script to name it accordingly? taking part of the file path as the new file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant but this should work:

```
find . -name total.txt | while read F ; do [[ $F =~ fixed.[^/]* ]] ; N=$(echo $BASH_REMATCH | sed s/fixed\.//) ; echo "cp $F $(dirname $F)/$N.xls" ; done
```

If you are happy with the output just remove the last echo, i.e. this:

```
echo "cp $F $(dirname $F)/$N.xls"
```

to this:

```
cp "$F" "$(dirname $F)/$N.xls"
```

Note, if the .txt and .xls contents will always remain the same you can use ln instead of cp -- one file, two names.

Comment: Thanks @Wayne, would you mind to explain a little more on the method?
I did some searching, $BASH_REMATCH actually take in all '=~' results. what about the N part ?

Comment: Yes, $BASH_REMATCH will be an array of all matches. But knowing there is only one match you can use $BASH_REMATCH instead of ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}. To improve the script you should actually wrap all the variables in double quotes and check the failure/success return of the match before using $BASH_REMATCH. The N=$(...) part is just removing the string "fixed." from the match, leaving just the part you want as the file name.

Comment: wow thanks @Wayne Vosberg, one last thing, due to some unforeseen circumstance, the path has some slight changes as shown in the above update, I tried [[ $F =~ /"fixed.[^/]*" ]] and [[ $F =~ /fixed.[^/]* ]], both gives same output of matching twice of the 'fixed' ?! may i know how to get only 5 files instead of 10 files?

Comment: also did tried $BASH_REMATCH[0] . still not workable.

Comment: Try [[ $F =~ fixed\.[^/]* ]] and ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} (you need the curly brackets).

Comment: I got it ! Thank you.